# Fade/dissolve when changing UIImageView's image with percentage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I want to change a UIImageView Image from one Image to another. **But i don't want it to animate completely to the end. I just want it to do the dissolve for a percentage.** The result should be a new image containing both images like i would have stopped the animation at some point and kept the result.

I know that this does all the animation from start to end:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.25;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
view1.hidden = YES;
view2.hidden = NO;
```

But then i have just changed the image. I want it to stay "merged" at a certain percentage. Is this somehow possible? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This Extension works for me:**

```
extension UIImage {
    static func mergeImage(imageA: UIImage, imageB:UIImage, percentage: CGFloat) -> UIImage{

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageA.size, false, 0.0)

        imageA.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1-percentage)

        imageB.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), blendMode: .normal, alpha: percentage)

        let mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return mergedImage!;
    }
}
```